# how to get element by classname with frame in selenium

Tags: selenium

```html
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="bootbox-close-button close"
            data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
      ×
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Search » User</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="bootbox-body">
      <div class="" data-popup-search="" data-title-modal="Search » ">
        <iframe data-iframe="iframe" id="iframe" name="iframe" frameborder="0"
                src="/users/search/os:ios" width="100%" height="400px">
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button data-bb-handler="success" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
      Close
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have 2 frame. I get the index frame with:

```java
driver.switchTo().frame(2)
```

I try to find an element by classname:

```java
driver.findElement(By.className("bootbox-body")).getText();
```

When I run this, sometimes I don't get an element.

@notes: 2 Frames have `classname("bootbox-body")`

Please help me. 
Thanks

Comment: have you tried just use a wait command for page complete load ?

Comment: if both frame having same class then find element by XPATH.

Comment: Hi Helping Hands,
Thanks you, but if html change,xpath not use

Comment: Hi aberna,
i try use a wait time for page load, and it run pass
Thanks Aberna